# How to maintain text in popup control even if click outside popup control

Tags: windows-phone

In my windows phone application I add one popup control for user login.
If user enter his credentials and click outside popup control then the data vanishes.
how to maintain data in popup even if user clicked outside popup?
Is there any property so that we can make background page ideal when popup window comes?

Answer (score 0):

use IsolatedStorage for that to maintain data.
see the link 
http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/06/windows-phone-7-mango-tutorial-12-using.html

hope this will help you...